# My PC randomly works and sometimes it doesn't

Tags: boot, display, gpu, desktop-computer

I have a custom built PC, I'll write specs at the end of post. I am facing a unique problem: whenever I try to turn on my PC everything in my case lights up, all fans spin but monitor shows "no signal" (monitor & HDMI is working - tested on different machine) but after multiple resets (force restart) it boots properly. It is random, sometimes even after multiple boot it doesn't work. But today after reset it worked. I am not able to pin point where the problem is. Tried removing external GPU (GTX 1650) and boot with Intel's integrated graphics but no luck.

Once the PC boots up, it runs for hours without giving any kind of issue. Only problem is getting it started.

I googled a lot. Removed every detachable component from motheboard and put it back on. Yet facing same issue. Below are my specs:

- Intel G4560 on Gigabyte H110M-S2 mobo
- 16 GB Corsair Vengeance RAMm at 2400 MHz (2x 8 GB)
- Zotac GTX 1650 OC 4 GB
- Artis 500W SMPS

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate saying it, it's either your CPU or your motherboard. I had similar cases on two separate custom computers. One took multiple attempts to start it, but once it started it worked great. That turned out to be the motherboard. On the other everything would light up, but I'd get no signal to monitor. That ended up being the CPU.

I wish I could give better news, but I guarantee one or the other is going out.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in the past and it turned out to be the power supply not providing enough power at boot.

I would try to start the PC, it started once or twice then it would shut down pretty quickly. Only after 2-3 times it would start properly and remain turned on.

The problem stopped happening after replacing a few hard drives with SSDs (I had 6 HDDs)